# Bound on the expectation of a random variable when dominated in some sense by another?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables supported over $\mathbb{R}$ with finite expectation. For all measurable $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have that:

$$\mathrm{Pr}(X \in S) \leq c \cdot\mathrm{Pr}(Y \in S), $$
for some constant $c > 1$.

For example, if $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and $Y$ is a random variable with density:

$$p_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{2}\phi(y) & y\leq 0 \\
      \frac{3}{2}\phi(y) & y > 0 \\
   \end{cases}
$$
where $\phi$ is the standard normal p.d.f. is an example of such an $X$ and $Y$ that satisfy this condition for $c = 2$.
Can we say anything about a bound on $\mathbb{E}[X]$ in terms of $c$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y]$?

I think it is likely possible to do something here, but not sure where to start.

Comment: What does $X \in S$ mean when $S \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Sorry, typo! Fixed it.

Comment: We may have $EX=EY=0$ so the ratio may not even be defined.

Comment: @J1996 can you give an example of the $X$ and $Y$ distributions?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, I see why that is a bad formulation. Tried to fix it here.

Comment: @Sal, I think this is an example? Let me know if something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such bound exists in general if $c >1$.

Here is a counter-example. Assume $X \sim \mathcal{D}$, WLOG mean $0$. Let $Y$ be a mixture, i.e. $Y\sim \frac{1}{c} \mathcal{D} + \frac{c-1}{c}\mathcal{N}(\mu_Y,1)$, which certainly satisfies our condition.

Then $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \frac{c-1}{c}\mu_Y$. This can be made arbitrarily small or large, independent of the mean of $X$, so no relationship exists in general.

When $c = 1$, we have
$$\mathrm{Pr}(X \in S) \leq \mathrm{Pr}(Y \in S) \Rightarrow \mathrm{Pr}(X \in S) = \mathrm{Pr}(Y \in S) \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[Y]$$
so the two expecations are equal in this case.

Comment: Why is it that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[Y]$ when $c=1$?

Comment: @JohnB updated with explanation.