# Relating the expectation of two random variables that mutually $c$-dominate one another?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables supported on $\mathbb{R}$, with finite expectation $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ respectively. We say that $X$ is $c$-dominated by $Y$ ($c \geq 1$) if for all measurable sets $S \subset \mathbb{R}$:

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Pr}(X \in S) \leq c \cdot\mathrm{Pr}(Y \in S).
\end{equation}

In general, $c$-domination tells us nothing about the mean gap $\mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[Y]$ when $c >1$, but we know that the gap is zero when $c = 1$. [Proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4397043/bound-on-the-expectation-of-a-random-variable-when-dominated-in-some-sense-by-an/4397104#4397104).

Now, what if we have know that $X$ and $Y$ mutually $c$-dominate one another? That is:

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Pr}(X \in S) \leq c \cdot\mathrm{Pr}(Y \in S).
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Pr}(Y \in S) \leq c \cdot\mathrm{Pr}(X \in S).
\end{equation}

In such a case, it seems reasonable that the mean gap cannot be arbitrarily large, at least with respect to the scale of the problem. In this case, it seems reasonable that there should be some kind of general relationship between $c$, $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y]$.

Does anyone have suggestions about how one might derive an inequality relating these quantities?

Answer (score 1):

Simply integrating or summing (whatever is your case), we get
$$
\mathbb{E}[|X|] \le c \,\mathbb{E}[|Y|]
\quad\text{and}\quad
\mathbb{E}[|Y|] \le c \,\mathbb{E}[|X|].
$$
This gives
$$
\bigl|\,\log\mathbb{E}[|X|]-\log\mathbb{E}[|Y|]\,\bigr|\le \log c.
$$
In particular, when $X$ and $Y$ take only nonnegative values we get
$$
\bigl|\,\log\mathbb{E}[X]-\log\mathbb{E}[Y]\,\bigr|\le \log c.
$$

Comment: I do not see how you got "$\mathbb{E}[X] \le c \,\mathbb{E}[Y]
\text{ and }
\mathbb{E}[Y] \le c \,\mathbb{E}[X]$" in particular if $\mathbb{E}[X]$  and $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ have opposite signs

Comment: @Henry It is simply an integral, so it is quite immediate.

Comment: Suppose $X=+6$ with probability $\frac23$ and $X=-6$  with probability $\frac13$ and $Y=-X$, so $\mathbb{E}[X] =2$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y] = -2$.  Then clearly $\Pr(X \in S) \leq 2 \cdot \Pr(Y \in S)$ and  $\Pr(Y \in S) \leq 2 \cdot \Pr(X \in S)$ for all $S$.  But $\mathbb{E}[X]  \not \le  2\mathbb{E}[Y]$.  You also get $\bigl|\,\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[Y]\,\bigr|  =4 \not\le 2-1$ which I think is a different issue related to scale

Comment: @Henry Indeed, I corrected it now how it is possible to correct. Thanks.

Comment: As I noted very clearly: "I corrected it now how it is possible to correct". In case you can add something that is nontrivial please do, otherwise we are done here.

Comment: When I commented 2 minutes ago, I could see your absolute values but not your logarithms